# How do you store non-persistent user-specific data in SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We have a WebPart that generates user-specific file paths and should use them across multiple functions.

```
namespace BlaWebPart.BlaWebPart
{
    #region Class ADATA
    public class ADATA
    {
        public string fileNameFull { get; set; } = "";
        ...
    }
}
```

"fileNameFull" contais user name and is initialized in one method and used in x methods. It works until a second user uses this WebPart. Then the first user has wrong path. Do I have to build dictionary for each user-specific member variable or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _Example = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    private static string Example
    {
        get {
                _Example.TryGetValue(LoginName, out string ret);
                return ret; 
            }  
        set { _Example[LoginName] = value; }
    }
```

I got LoginName from SPContext.

I have not blocked multiple execution of the methods, as I'm sure that each user creates his/her own WebPart instance.

If we had been allowed to use cookies, it would probably have been possible to store something there too, or at least to use the session id as a key for the dictionaries.